# How to make a range selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to us a `range selector` with two dependent input and a chart in my website , exactly like this one in Google page for Company Distribution.

https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener

but I don't want to write it from the scratch by myself.

Is there a good library for it? I want to make exactly similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/) plugin - JRange. It is in github and is easy to use.

Comment: it doesn't have vertical value